# Wont load content while scrolling - mysql error

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am trying to make a page which should load content while scrolling down.

I have search for a solution, and didn't any. All them which refrence to the same error do not have a useful solution for my problem. SO PLEASE DO NOT DUPLICATE TO ANOTHER ANSWER!

First_load.php and second_load.php are included in load_data.php, and the config.php are included in load_data.php. - I Think the problem is something to be in second_load.php where it fail.

I use mysqli

I am getting this mysqli error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ALL/load_data_scrolling/load_first.php on
>   line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ALL/load_data_scrolling/load_first.php on
>   line 3

Here my code
Config.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "loadcontent");
?>
```

load_data.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];
$action=$_GET['action'];

if($action <> "get")
{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Load Data while scrolling 9lessons tutorials</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="9lessons.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function last_msg_funtion() 
        { 

           var ID=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
            $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
            $.post("load_data.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID,

            function(data){
                if (data != "") {
                $(".message_box:last").after(data);         
                }
                $('div#last_msg_loader').empty();
            });
        };  

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
               last_msg_funtion();
            }
        }); 

    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<div>
<h2><a href="http://9lessons.blogspot.com">9Lessons.blogspot.com</a></h2>
</div>

<?php

include('load_first.php');

?>
<div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
else
{

include('load_second.php');     

        }
        ?>
```

load_first.php

```
<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY mes_id DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msgID= $row['mes_id'];
        $msg= $row['msg'];

?>
<div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>"  align="left" class="message_box" >
<span class="number"><?php echo $msgID; ?></span><?php echo $msg; ?> 
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

load_second.php

```
<?php
$last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];
 $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mes_id < '$last_msg_id' ORDER BY mes_id DESC LIMIT 5");
 $last_msg_id="";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        $msgID= $row['mes_id'];
        $msg= $row['msg'];
    ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $msgID; ?>"  align="left" class="message_box" >
<span class="number"><?php echo $msgID; ?></span><?php echo $msg; ?> 
</div>


<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not opening the connection to your database properly. When used in a procedural style, `mysqli_connect` returns something falsey if the connection fails. You can get more information by updating your `Config.php` accordingly:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "loadcontent");
if (!$con) { 
    die('Connect error: (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

PHP was pointing you to the correct error location; "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given" was pointing to the second line of your `load_first.php`. Parameter 1 was `$con` - the first time you'd tried to use it - and PHP said "I expected this to be a `mysqli` object, but it was actually a boolean!". Suggesting that your `$con` wasn't getting set properly. The second error's a knock-on from that, as `mysqli_query` will return `null` if it can't query the database, and `mysqli_fetch_array` can't fetch an array from `null` data.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't connect to the database. - Cause I have used $Con instead of $con.